# How can I use constructor in the Flutter

Tags: flutter, class, constructor

I want to do a study that calculates monthly electricity consumption using the values entered in the textfield using the constructor. I created the constructors but I couldn't find how to call them inside the widgets.
I have a few mistakes.The first is the parameters of a new object. The second is the function definition in the `onPressed` method.

```
class _MyHomePageState extends State {
  TextEditingController t1 = TextEditingController();
  TextEditingController t2 = TextEditingController();
  TextEditingController t3 = TextEditingController();
  ElektrikliCihaz elektrikliCihaz_1 =
      ElektrikliCihaz(cihazAdi, cihazKW, gunlukSaatKullanim);
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Container(
          child: Column(
        children: [
          TextField(
            controller: t1,
            decoration: InputDecoration(hintText: "Cihaz Adi"),
          ),
          TextField(
            controller: t2,
            decoration: InputDecoration(hintText: "Cihaz Gücü (KW)"),
          ),
          TextField(
            controller: t3,
            decoration: InputDecoration(hintText: "Günlük Kullanılan Saat"),
          ),
          ElevatedButton(
            child: Text("Hesapla"),
            onPressed: aylikTuketim() {
              setState(() {});
            },
          )
        ],
      )),
    );
  }
}

class ElektrikliCihaz {
  String cihazAdi;
  int cihazKW;
  int gunlukSaatKullanim;
  ElektrikliCihaz(this.cihazAdi, this.cihazKW, this.gunlukSaatKullanim);
  int aylikTuketim() {
    int aylikKullanim;
    aylikKullanim = cihazKWgunlukSaatKullanim30;
    return aylikKullanim;
  }
}
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

To access value from textfield use `t1.text;`. If you want to create instance of a class in `onPressed` do it like so:

```
ElevatedButton(
            child: Text("Hesapla"),
            onPressed: () {
              ElektrikliCihaz elektrikliCihaz_1 =
              ElektrikliCihaz(t1.text, int.parse(t2.text), int.parse(t3.text)); //create class instance
              //then to use class function
              elektrikliCihaz_1.aylikTuketim() //use whatever parameters needed I don't speak turkish
            },
          )
```